# Migration from Icefaces to Primefaces JavascriptContext.applicationFocus(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "");

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2, icefaces

I am migrating from old Icefaces to the newest Primefaces 5.3.5 and I need to migrate this

```
JavascriptContext.applicationFocus(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "reportSettingsForm:pageOrientationRd:_1");
```

How can it be migrated, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work without testing it.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PrimeFaces.focus('reportSettingsForm:pageOrientationRd:_1');");
```